# How to Dynamically Set Max Qty in Touchspin Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone can help me?
I tried this code to dynamically set the value of maximum qty, but it still doesn't work.

This is my code :

```
var max = document.getElementById("max_qty");
    $("input[name='qty_total']").TouchSpin({
            min: 0,
            max: max,
            step: 0.01,
            decimals: 2,
            boostat: 5,
            maxboostedstep: 10
        }
    );
```

Comment: Are these the docs for your lib: https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Yeah, true.
I tried to set dinamically but the value is still not can be change / still static

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_max_qty = document.getElementById("max_qty");
$("input[name='qty_total']").trigger("touchspin.updatesettings", {
  max: new_max_qty
});
```

Reference: https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.